# Derivative of $\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$$

\begin{align}
f'(x) & ={1\over 2} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \cdot {x+1-(x-1)\over (x+1)^2} \\[10pt]
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cdot{2\over (x+1)^2} =\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cdot{1\over (x+1)^2}
\end{align}

Is it valid to write $ (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^{\frac{-1}{2}}= \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$ ?

Comment: Yes it is. Your work looks good.

Comment: @JohnDouma I was not sure as wolfram did not simplify the expression this way http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+sqrt%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29

Comment: Note that the derivative is perhaps easier by writing $\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1-2}{x+1}=1-\frac{2}{x+1}=1-2(x+1)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, you need to apply some constraints for the variable $x$,

for all $x>1$,  it will be valid to write $$\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$$

Comment: But the same constraint will apply on ${1\over\sqrt{{x-1\over x+1}}}$